# How to add/remove dynamically a layout (Relative, Linear,...) inside another one?

Tags: android, listview, layout, dynamic, scrollview

I'm writing an app which ask the user to fill a dynamic form.

The user can add or remove dynamically a component (Button, EditText, ...) from this page.

for that, i created a personnal adapter with a listView and add or remove an element when it's required. But if you add a lot of elements, the layout will be quickly full so i used a scrollView.

After a long surf on internet, i read that's not recommanded to create a ListView inside a ScrollView (2 list can make conflicts).
In fact, when i use the both, the size of the ListView is not refreshed. I tried to fix this problem with a ViewTreeObserver but that's not a clean solution... it required to many CPU... :/

After that, i tried to create a class "extends LinearLayout" but i can't see how i can catch the event from a button click to add or remove a an componant.

Is it possible to create an object (from an xml layout) and add or remove it dynamically (different ID,...) ?

How can i make a dynamic page ? Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help !!!

Here is a picture of my application : http://postimg.org/image/5shoatvl1/

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate an XML object (like a LinearLayout or a ListView) using the LayoutInflater: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

After you do this you can add any View to a ViewGroup, for instance: If you'd like to add a button to a ScrollView you can just call:

```
scrollView.addView(button);
```

You can do this for any object that implements the View class. This includes LinearLayout and ScrollView.

You can remove a View by calling removeView on the target view it's parent. For instance that you'd want to remove the button you simply call:

```
scrollView.removeView(button);
```

You can also iterate trough all views and remove a view that meets a certain condition like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
   View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
   if(v.meetsReq()) {
       //do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create layout file that can be display only edittext.and when the edittext append in your view dynemically then inflate that view and add in your main view.so whenever you add or delelte any of the view dynemically using inflator.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) viewImageDetailView
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.xml_edittext, null, false);
```

i hope this is useful to you...